# Python Parse a CAN log file (.asc or blf) that contains CAN-TP Trame (ISO-TP)

Tags: python, parsing, ascii, can-bus

Hi i'm searching for a solution (Library or tool) to decode a CAN log file (.asc). This log file contains CAN-TP Frame along side normale CAN Frame so the only possible way is to parse the file and extract the payload of each frame , then decode it.

- **My question is**: Is there any Library in python to do the parsing for
  me then i will be able to decode the file by reading the file. Here is an exemple

```
     7388.173462   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             10 8E F5 10 00 00 88 FF                           
     7388.173644   CAN 1   21                   CAN Frame      Rx     3     3             30 00 0A                                          
     7388.185098   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             21 01 02 03 04 10 01 01                           
     7388.195350   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             22 02 03 04 05 06 07 08                           
     7388.205596   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             23 04 FF 69 EB 60 86 93                           
     7388.215839   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             24 8B 3C CE 2C 9E 64 DC                           
     7388.226087   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             25 AC EA 1A 92 59 18 E7                           
     7388.236327   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             26 5E 8C 17 94 8D 31 63                           
     7388.246575   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             27 22 D3 70 12 3F 69 13                           
     7388.256815   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             28 2A ED 73 98 91 9E 6E                           
     7388.267057   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             29 66 14 F7 62 7B 0A 54
```

What i'm loocking for is a parser to format the log as so:

```
 7388.173462   CAN 1   20                   CAN Frame      Tx     8     8             10 8E F5 10 00 00 88 FF 21 01 02 03 04 10 01 01 22 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 23 04 FF 69 EB 60 86 93 24 8B 3C CE 2C 9E 64 DC
```

Comment: the project [python-can](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/5859cdcfff88fec45f52f89b52dcfee3cea63a86/can/io/asc.py) seems to support it

Comment: @Tranbi Thanks for your answer but the think is i want to do the parsing offline and python-can can't run out of the box

Comment: what do you mean by that? if you install `python-can` you should be able to read your .asc files with `from can import io; can_trace = io.asc.ASCReader("file.asc"); for frm in can_trace: #do stuffs with frm`

Comment: I'm not sure that the format of your asc files matches the one described on the [project page](https://bitbucket.org/tobylorenz/vector_asc/src/47556e1a6d32c859224ca62d075e1efcc67fa690/src/Vector/ASC/tests/unittests/data/CAN_Log_Trigger_3_2.asc?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) though

Answer (score 0):

With following code I am able to read the data from a blf file:

```
import can
test = can.BLFReader("Short.blf")
for elem in test:
    if elem.arbitration_id == 0x1c400000:
        print(elem.data.hex())
        # do other stuff here
```

instead of can.BLFReader you can use can.ASCReader to read file in asc format.
You can provide a parser in the for loop to operate on data as you prefer.

using Requests and Response from uds on can you should be able to parse uds frames:

```
import can
from udsoncan import Request,Response
test = can.BLFReader("Short.blf")
for elem in test:
    if elem.arbitration_id == 0x1c400000:
        response=Response.from_payload(payload)
        print(response)
```